# rails server and console not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Using `rbenv` and `Rails 4.2.6`, when I run `bundle exec rails s` or `bundle exec rails c`, I see the following:

```
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
```

That's all, nothing else happens. If I then `stop spring`, and `run bundle exec rails c`, the following appears:

```
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_data_typed_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_data_typed_object_alloc
  Referenced from: /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Any idea what's wrong here? Thanks!

**Update: add content of gemfile and ouput of bundle install**

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.3.1"
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'simple_form'
gem "puma"
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
gem "rails_12factor"
gem 'slack-ruby-client'
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'rails-4-x'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Output of `bundle install`:

```
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using sass 3.4.22
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using dotenv 2.1.1
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using gli 2.14.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using ruby_dep 1.3.1
Using lumberjack 1.0.10
Using nenv 0.3.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Using rspec-support 3.4.1
Using hashie 3.4.4
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using pg 0.18.4
Using puma 3.4.0
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using spring 1.7.1
Using terminal-notifier-guard 1.7.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6.2
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using sprockets 3.6.1
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using notiffany 0.1.0
Using pry 0.10.3
Using rspec-core 3.4.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
Using faraday_middleware 0.10.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using rspec 3.4.0
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Using factory_girl 4.7.0
Using jbuilder 2.5.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using slack-ruby-client 0.7.4
Using guard 2.14.0
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using guard-rspec 4.7.2
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using railties 4.2.6
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Using simple_form 3.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using dotenv-rails 2.1.1
Using factory_girl_rails 4.7.0
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using quiet_assets 1.1.0
Using rails-i18n 4.0.8 from git://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n.git (at rails-4-x@129b9fb)
Using rspec-rails 3.4.2
Using rails 4.2.6
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using web-console 2.3.0
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Bundle complete! 25 Gemfile dependencies, 102 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

**Update 2 - added `bundle exec gem pristine --all`**

```
bundle exec gem pristine --all
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Restored rake-11.2.2
Restored i18n-0.7.0
Skipped json-1.8.3, it is a default gem
Restored minitest-5.9.0
Restored thread_safe-0.3.5
Restored tzinfo-1.2.2
Restored activesupport-4.2.6
Restored builder-3.2.2
Restored erubis-2.7.0
Restored mini_portile2-2.1.0
Restored pkg-config-1.1.7
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160620-6035-1m3373p.rb extconf.rb
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
/Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.6.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/nandersen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nandersen/Projects/the-lunch/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Could you show us your Gemfile, and the result of `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, I've added the information to the initial question @LarryLv.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `debug_inspector` gem, you could try to remove `web-console` gem in your Gemfile, `bundle install`, and run the server again.

UPDATE:

Or if you would like to keep the `web-console` gem, you could try to remove all the gems you have installed, and re-bundle install them again. According to this issue on [rails/web-console](https://github.com/rails/web-console/issues/175).

Comment: I did as you suggested but now the the first error appears again, it's not loading any farer than the first error message I posted in my question.

Comment: Could you try this `bundle exec gem pristine --all` and run `bundle exec rails c` again?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output from `bundle exec gem pristine --all`.

Comment: `bundle install` again, and make sure your `config/database.yml` file didn't specify `sqlite` as your adapter.

Comment: Ok I've run `bundle install`, which ran through without any problems. `sqlite` is not specified in the config file. Now when I run `bundle exec rails c` the problem is still there.

Comment: This seems like a tricky question, so I have to ask about some corner cases. Do you have both rvm and rbenv installed? Or, do you have rbenv installed both via manually `git clone` and homebrew?

Comment: Yeah I guess this is an exceptional case.. thanks for digging deeper! In the past I was using `rvm` but I think I've removed it correctly. I think I probably had `rbenv` installed both ways, as you suggested, until a couple of days ago. I removed the `~/.rbenv` folder and continued using the `brew version`. Should I maybe remove the `brew version` and remove the `~/.rbenv` folder again, and the pull it from github?

Comment: I would suggest you doing that, something must be wrong with your ruby environment. Remove all ruby version management tools, and re-install rbenv, ruby, and try again.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Would you recommend to install rbenv via github pull or brew?

Comment: I think either way will work just fine, and I installed it via github pull.

Comment: I've removed the `~/.rbenv` folder, uninstalled `rbenv` and `ruby-build` in homebrew and pulled `rbenv` and `ruby-build` from github, but the problem still exists. I don't know if it's important but running `bundle exec which sqlite3` says: `/usr/bin/sqlite3`. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: One more thing, your bundler is also newly installed after installing ruby again, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, when I've installed rbenv and ruby and then run `bundle`, it says `fish: Unknown command 'bundle'`. (I'm using the fish shell)

Comment: Could this be a hint? With freshly installed rbenv, ruby + bundler, when I run `gem list --local` it says: `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
bundler (1.12.5)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.0.17)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
test-unit (3.1.5)`. How can there be any installed gems at this point?

Comment: This is what ruby wants, once installed, also with these gems.